como puedo obtener el numero de celular en una app echa en ionic?
quiero obtener el numero de celular y almacenarla en una variable para posteriormente usar esa variable y ejecutar un servicio, use la librería Device pero solo me recupera información básica del celular como modelo, nombre etc habra alguna otra manera de obtenerlo?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
